# setting x-axis points distance in line graphs

Tags: matlab

I have x-axis value as 10, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000

and y-axis values between 0 and 1. I am comparing 10 values, with 10 line plots on single graph.

I want equal gap between the points of x-axis. I used the command: 
set(gca,'XTick',[10, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000])

But, it is not displaying equal gaps. What I mean to say is that x-axis should be divided into 6 (above) points with equal spaces, as in my graph, since variation is higher from point 10 to 250, so lines are very congested. Any help in this regard please?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that since your gaps are not evenly spaced, you wont get it (at least with the Matlab default drawing plot). You can try to make a log scale using

set(gca,'xscale','log')

that will make the space even at least the the second to last tick (approximately).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom XTickLabel for 1, 2, 3, ...

```
x = [10, 100, 250, 500, 1000, 2000];
y = randn(size(x));
plot(1:numel(x), y);
set(gca,'XTick', 1:numel(x));
set(gca,'XTickLabel', arrayfun(@num2str, x, 'UniformOutput', false));
```